# Is this set always convex?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis

**Question:** A region in the plane is called convex if the line segment joining any two points in the region lies wholly inside the region. In symbols, $R$ is convex if, for all $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in $R$, $(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2,\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) \in R$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

a) Prove that if $R$ and $S$ are convex, then $R \cap S$ is convex. *(No problem with this part)*

b) If $R$ and $S$ are convex, is $R \cup S$ always convex? Prove your answer. *(No problem with this part)*

c) Prove that if $R$ is convex, then the reflection of $R$ in the $x$-axis is convex. *(No problem with this part)*

d) If $R$ is convex, is the set,

$2R = \{(x,y):(x,y) = (2x',2y')$ for some $(x',y') \in R\}$

always convex? Prove your answer and illustrate with a diagram.

---

I've been successful in all parts except (d). I am not sure exactly what to do nor what this actually means. Any explanation or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it help if I write $2R=\{\langle 2x,2y\rangle:\langle x,y\rangle\in R\}$? The definition in the problem is unnecessarily clumsy. In other words, just double the coordinates of each point in $R$ to get the set $2R$.

Comment: Man, it's really difficult to be a good contributor these days on MathSE. All these gold star people churning out proofs before an initial student explainer can take a breath. Not necessarily a bad thing though, but us youngbloods have a much lower incentive of answering a question. I hate myself for being competitive in a task as noble as helping a fellow student though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y)=(2x',2y'), (u,v)=(2u',2v')\in 2R ,$ then $$t(x,y)+(1-t)(u,v)=2 (t(x',y')+(1-t)(u',v'))\in 2R $$ since $R$ is convex.